# Why require field validator in asp.net show error message on clear button click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have applied required field validator. In my code i have two buttons. When i click `create account` it works fine but when i click `clear` button it must only clear the values rather than showing error messages. I have a script manager and an update panel at the top.

```
<tr>
     <td>
         <asp:Label ID="lbConfirmPassword" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password: *"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="tbConfirmPassword" runat="server" MaxLength="25" type="password"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvConfirmPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" 
              ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ForeColor="red></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvPassword" runat="server" ControlToCompare="tbPassword" ControlToValidate="tbConfirmPassword" 
              Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid confirm password." ForeColor="red"></asp:CompareValidator>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr class="alert-success">
     <td colspan="2">
         <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" cssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" 
                                OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Create Account >>" />
         <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" cssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 
                                Text="Clear" onclick="btnClear_Click1"/>
         <asp:Label ID="lbMsg" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set CausesValidation of clear button to false

Answer (score 1):

Add CausesValidation="false"

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" 
           CausesValidation="false"
           cssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 
           Text="Clear" onclick="btnClear_Click1"/>
```